# Ponteiro para função em uma classe C++

Tags: c++

Estou com dificuldade em colocar um ponteiro para uma função em uma classe:

```
int Menu::validaescolha(){
    cout << 1232;
    return 1;
}
int Menu::inicial(){
    int (Menu::*funcs)() = &Menu::validaescolha;
    funcs();
    return 0;
}
```

Retornam esses erros:

1 - Erro (ativo)    E0109   expressões que precedem parênteses de chamada aparente devem possuir tipo de função (ponteiro-para-)

2 - Erro    C2064   o termo não pode ser avaliado como uma função recebendo 0 argumentos

To sem ideia do que fazer aqui...

Comment: Em C++ normalmente se usa `functors` ou melhor ainda *lambdas* na versões mais novas (já há 6 anos). Ponteiro para função é coisa de C. E tem vários erros aí.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como ficaria isso que quero usando o que você disse?

Comment: D á uma olhada nisso: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ponteiro para método é uma técnica não muito usada (acho eu), e por isso pouca gente conhece. Tive que pesquisar um pouco para descobrir que é preciso usar parênteses adicionais na utilização do ponteiro. Notar que é necessário ter um objeto para chamar o método através do ponteiro.

Isso se aplica a métodos não estáticos. Ponteiros para métodos estáticos não são especiais, são declarados da mesma maneira que ponteiros para funções "comuns" (que não são membros de uma classe).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Menu
{
   public:
      int validaEscolha();
      static int stValidaEscolha();
      int inicial();
};


int Menu::validaEscolha()
{
   cout << 1232 << endl;
   return 1;
}

int Menu::stValidaEscolha()
{
   cout << 1232 << endl;
   return 1;
}

int Menu::inicial()
{
   // ponteiro para método não estático
   int (Menu::*funcs)() = &Menu::validaEscolha;
   (this->*funcs)();

   // ponteiro para método estático
   int (*stFuncs)() = &Menu::stValidaEscolha;
   stFuncs();

   return 0;
}

int main()
{
   Menu m;
   m.inicial();
}
```

Comment: Boa. Complementando: Ponteiros para métodos tem tratamento especial pois tem de ser calculado o offset  dentro da classe. Funções estáticas não dependem de nenhuma instância da classe, por isso  são como funções livres.

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado @José X.

Comment: marque a resposta como aceita, por favor